# How to prevent user from changing date control which is linked to a textbox in VB6

Tags: vb6, datepicker, monthcalendar

`txtmonth = '01/2011'` (This is a textbox control)

I have a Date Control which should automatically display `January 2011`. The end user should not able to select month & year from the date control, only the day.

User should select only the date from that month. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the data range they can select by setting the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` properties.

This applies to both the DTPicker and the MonthCal controls.